# After CAReplicatorLayer animation in a `vc`'s `subview`, switch `vc` comes a strange issue

Tags: ios, animation, careplicatorlayer

`CAReplicator` did not keep the state after the switch `vc`:

`Dots` of `CAReplicator` did not keep its scale after the `vc` switch back.

As you see, the circle animation is created by `CAReplicator`.

after the main `vc` switch to another `vc`, then switch back, the `Circle`'s `dots` become very small. witch is set in the initial.

My code is below:

In the main `vc`:

```
 func initUI() {

    let lml_frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 64, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 400)
    lml_digtal_view = LMLDigitalDazzleAnimationView.init(frame: lml_frame)
    self.view.addSubview(lml_digtal_view!)
}
```

In the `LMLDigitalDazzleAnimationView`:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LMLDigitalDazzleAnimationView: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    }
    */

    var initFrame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)

    var fromColor = UIColor.init(red: 240/255.0, green: 77.0/255.0, blue: 48.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    var toColor = UIColor.init(red: 220.0/255.0, green: 28.0/255.0, blue: 44.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

    var money:Float? = 1200.25 {

        didSet {
    
        
        }
    }

    override  init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initFrame = frame
        initUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func initUI(){
    
    
    let gradul_layer = CAGradientLayer.init()
    gradul_layer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: initFrame.width, height: initFrame.height)
    gradul_layer.colors = [
        fromColor,
        toColor
    ]
    gradul_layer.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.3)
    gradul_layer.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.7)
    
    layer.addSublayer(gradul_layer)
    
    let wave_view0 = KHWaveView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: initFrame.height - 80, width: initFrame.width, height: 80))
    //wave_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    wave_view0.waveColor = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    wave_view0.waveSpeed = 1.3
    wave_view0.waveTime = 0
    wave_view0.wave()
    self.addSubview(wave_view0)
    
    let wave_view = KHWaveView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: initFrame.height - 80, width: initFrame.width, height: 80))
    //wave_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    wave_view.waveColor = UIColor.white
    wave_view.waveSpeed = 1.0
    wave_view.waveTime = 0
    wave_view.wave()
    
    
    self.addSubview(wave_view)
    
    animateCircle()
    
    animateDigitalIcrease(money: money!)
    
    
    
    }

    func animateCircle() -> Void {
    
        let r = CAReplicatorLayer()
        r.bounds = CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width:260.0, height:260.0)
        r.cornerRadius = 10.0
        r.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        r.position = CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width / 2.0, y: 160)
    
        self.layer.addSublayer(r)
    
        let dot = CALayer()
        dot.bounds = CGRect(x:0.0, y :0.0, width:6.0, height:6.0)
        dot.position = CGPoint(x:100.0, y:10.0)
        dot.backgroundColor = UIColor(white:1, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        dot.cornerRadius = 3.0
    
        r.addSublayer(dot)
    
        let nrDots: Int = 32
        r.instanceCount = nrDots
        let angle = CGFloat(2*M_PI) / CGFloat(nrDots)
        r.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0)
    
        let duration:CFTimeInterval = 1.5
        let shrink = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        shrink.fromValue = 1.0
        shrink.toValue = 1.0 // 0.5
        shrink.duration = duration
        shrink.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    
        dot.add(shrink, forKey: nil)
    
        r.instanceDelay = duration/Double(nrDots)
    
        dot.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    
        delay(delay: duration) {
        
            let turn_key_path = "transform.rotation"
            let turn_ani = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: turn_key_path)
            turn_ani.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            turn_ani.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            turn_ani.toValue = M_PI*2
            turn_ani.duration = 2.0
            turn_ani.repeatCount = 2
            r.add(turn_ani, forKey: turn_key_path)
       
        }
    
    }

    func delay(delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()){
    
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
    }

    func animateDigitalIcrease(money :Float){

        let frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 80)
        let counterLabel = LMLDigitalIncreaseLabel.init(frame: frame, andDuration: 2.0, andFromValue: 0, andToValue: money)
        counterLabel?.center = CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: 130)
        self.addSubview(counterLabel!)
    
        counterLabel?.start()
     
        delay(delay: 5.0) {
            counterLabel?.stop()
            self.animateFadeShowSmallMoney()
        }
    
    }

    func animateFadeShowSmallMoney(){
  
        let border_view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
        border_view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        border_view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        border_view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        border_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        border_view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    
    
        let small_money_frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 30)
        let small_money = UILabel.init(frame: small_money_frame)
        small_money.center = border_view.center
        small_money.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
      
        small_money.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        small_money.text = "mo:" + String(format:"%.2f", money!)
        small_money.textColor = UIColor.white
        border_view.addSubview(small_money)
    
        border_view.alpha = 0.0
        self.addSubview(border_view)
        border_view.center = CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.size.width/2.0, y: 220)
    
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { 
            border_view.alpha = 1.0
        }
    
    }

}
```

My code is not good, you can advice me how to encapsulate a animation class better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attention, I solve my issue:

```
    delay(delay: duration) {

        let turn_key_path = "transform.rotation"
        let turn_ani = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: turn_key_path)
        turn_ani.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        turn_ani.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        turn_ani.toValue = M_PI*2
        turn_ani.duration = 2.0
        turn_ani.repeatCount = 2
        r.add(turn_ani, forKey: turn_key_path)
        dot.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1) // add this line solve my issue.
    }
```